# Query em HQL usando Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Como fazer uma query para retornar o resultado a abaixo em HQL

**Resultado**

```
| quantidade | quantidade erro |   desc   |

|     2      |         1       |  TESTE 1 |
|     3      |         2       |  TESTE 2 |
|     1      |         1       |  TESTE 3 |
```

**Tabela**

```
| DESC    |  ERRO |

| TESTE 1 |   0   |
| TESTE 1 |   1   |
| TESTE 2 |   1   |
| TESTE 2 |   0   |
| TESTE 2 |   1   |
| TESTE 3 |   1   |
```

Comment: Eu, sinceramente, não entendi a lógica da consulta. Você poderia explicar melhor o objetivo da consulta e/ou você tem um SQL que gere esta consulta, para podermos nos guiar na construção do HQL/JPQL?

Answer (score 1):

Precisas de agrupar os dados por Descrição e fazer uma contagem (`count`) para a quantidade agrupada, depois um `SUM` para contar o número de erros - `ERRO`, e no final acrescentar a descrição:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as quantidade, SUM(ERRO) as quantidadeErro, desc
FROM tabela
GROUP BY DESC
```